# X11 not working on Cygwin

Tags: linux, cygwin, xorg, gnome

I am fed up with the default Windows interface so I decided to install Cygwin and run a gnome shell on startup.

When the installation was done, I went into Cygwin and started X with this command `xinit gnome-session` and I got this error and the shell closed shortly thereafter.

[image: Screenshot of gnome error]

and this is the output log

[image: Screenshot of output log]

I think it has something to do with display drivers but I really don't know when I was installing Cygwin it came up with an error but stupidly I pressed OK without reading it, so help.

Comment: For textual output, copying the text is far more beneficial for us than screenshots.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714

Comment: $ xinit gnome-session

Welcome to the XWin X Server
Vendor: The Cygwin/X Project
Release: 1.19.2.0
OS: CYGWIN_NT-10.0 2016-MP06NE55 2.8.0(0.309/5/3) 2017-04-01 20:47 x86_64
OS: Windows 10  [Windows NT 10.0 build 14393] (Win64)
Package: version 1.19.2-1 built 2017-03-09

XWin was started with the following command line:

X :0

(II) xorg.conf is not supported
(II) See http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html for more information
LoadPreferences: /home/RYC0001/.XWinrc not found

Comment: LoadPreferences: Loading /etc/X11/system.XWinrc
LoadPreferences: Done parsing the configuration file...
winDetectSupportedEngines - RemoteSession: no
winDetectSupportedEngines - DirectDraw4 installed, allowing ShadowDDNL

Comment: winDetectSupportedEngines - Returning, supported engines 00000005
winSetEngine - Using Shadow DirectDraw NonLocking
winScreenInit - Using Windows display depth of 32 bits per pixel
winWindowProc - WM_SIZE - new client area w: 1902 h: 983
winFinishScreenInitFB - Masks: 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff
MIT-SHM extension disabled due to lack of kernel support

Comment: XFree86-Bigfont extension local-client optimization disabled due to lack of shared memory support in the kernel
(EE) AIGLX: No native OpenGL in modes with a root window
(II) IGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
(II) IGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
(II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
winPointerWarpCursor - Discarding first warp: 951 491
(--) 5 mouse buttons found
(--) Setting autorepeat to delay=500, rate=31
(--) Windows keyboard layout: "00000409" (00000409) "US", type 4
(--) Found matching XKB configuration "English (USA)"

Comment: (--) Model = "pc105" Layout = "us" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
Rules = "base" Model = "pc105" Layout = "us" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
winProcEstablishConnection - winInitClipboard returned.
winClipboardThreadProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
OS maintains clipboard viewer chain: yes
winClipboardProc - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the display.
xinit: connection to X server lost
winClipboardProc - winClipboardFlushWindowsMessageQueue trapped WM_QUIT message, exiting main loop.

waiting for X server to shut down winClipboardProc - XDestroyWindow succeeded.

Comment: winDeinitMultiWindowWM - Noting shutdown in progress
(II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

Comment: @Fish4203 edit the question and add the necessary information. Comments are not for them. And put code inside backticks `\`like this\`` to make it readable

Answer (score 1):

To run the the Xserver with the window manager in  cygwin use:

`startxwin`

and if you need to disable the WGL accelerator

`startxwin -- -nowgl`

See
https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using.html#using-starting
for details.

Answer (score 0):

Message

> libGL error: Screen is not Windows-DRI capable

indicates that we wanted to use direct, hardware-accelerated OpenGL ('Windows-DRI'), but that the server didn't allow it.

This could be due to:

- server option `-nowgl`
- windowing mode doesn't permit wgl (i.e. not `-multiwindow`)
- display driver does not support WGL (i.e. the default VGA driver)

etc.

[More info](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using-glx.html).

Try run with `-multiwindow`:

```
xinit gnome-session -- -multiwindow
```

Comment: it just does the same thing except in a smaller window

Comment: Try with `-nowgl`: `xinit gnome-session -- -multiwindow -nowgl`

Comment: still, doesn't work I can boot into Xorg

Comment: this is the error i get when i run gnome-session from within x 
$ gnome-session
gnome-session-binary: PID 11044: WARNING: Using null backend for session tracking
Unable to init server: Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: Connection refused